# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error for Webfonts on Firefox/Mac

Tags: .htaccess, access-control

i try to load some web fonts from webtype but on Firefox/Mac i always geht an Access-Control-Allow-Origin-Error.

htaccess:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

base href is also set:

```
<base href="http://XXX.XXX.ch">
```

Error: CORS-Header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing

Any idea to solve the problem?

thanks 
thomas

Comment: You need to share more context.

Comment: hi anne
thanks - the webfont is not showing (it's only shows times instead of nobel) - only on FF and Chrome. The include script of the webfont is 
    <link href="//cloud.webtype.com/css/e74625c1-7665-46ef-9346-a7e0fc7ab566.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

do you need more info?

Comment: Does the cloud.webtype.com server have that header set?

Comment: They told me that on her site is everything ok! i cannot check that, or can i? how?

Comment: Through the browser's developer console and such. Should be quite easy to inspect the headers of responses. If you can put a demo online somewhere that'd make things much easier.

Comment: Hi Anne, i made a demo online: http://branders2016.branders-development.ch/fonttest.php  (only FF and Chrome). Thanks.

Comment: That test works in Firefox (Nightly) on Mac for me.